# Styling a paragraph element with css

Tags: html, css

I for some reason my text that says "Make this photo a moment?" is overflowing and not displaying right? What could I be doing wrong?

Here is a my source and a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tPSfy/

Comment: You're setting the width of it to 70px. Either expand the width to fill the space you actually want, or use `overflow:hidden;`

Comment: I just looked at your fiddle, but I'm not sure what the "correct" version of the page would look like. Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the width from the following CSS IDs (#share-action.moment p & #share-action p ), Check below code. Fixed width is the reason its not formatting correctly.

```
#share-action.moment p {
    color: #444444;
    float: left;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 /*   width: 70px; */
}
#share-action p {
    float: left;
    font-family: Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 /*   width: 70px; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of width: 70px

```
#share-action.moment p
    {
    ...
    width: auto;
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For a quick fix, you may replace the `p` tag with a `span` tag, if you want to keep that `p` in there, remove the width of `70px`, this is what is pushing that text below the div.

```
#share-action.moment p /* remove width or place width: auto */
```

On further inspection, you have two `share-action` `ids` which are not allowed; `ids` are unique `classes` may be repeated

Comment: `share-actions` and `share-action-left` are repeated as well.

Answer (score 0):

remove the `<p>` surrounding that text, or change the `width` assigned to `<p>`.

Answer (score 0):

it's float:left so its size has no influence on its container. you can add an empty element with `clear:both` to expand the container